# How to add all data to a facet_wrap ggplot standard error plot (where facet wrap is already being used to denote a factor)

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, standard-error

I'm trying to plot a multipane figure which displays standard error plots of various biodiversity metrics. I have data from five rivers but I want to display the five rivers independently (currently called in the facet_warp function) but I want to add a sixth graph that plots all data combined as standard error (with this graph being the final graph in the row of 6). I can plot a sixth graph as scatter plot or small SE but not the same format as the other graphs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance! Code I am using for one metric is below.

```
sum = summarySE(Summer, 
                measurevar="Feve", 
                groupvars=c("Habitat","River"))

str(sum)

pd = position_dodge(.5)

fig1 <- ggplot(sum, aes(x=Habitat, 
                        y=Feve, 
                        colour = Habitat)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Feve-se, 
                    ymax=Feve+se), 
                width=.2, size=0.7, position=pd) +
  geom_point(position = pd, size = 6)


Feve1<- fig1 +
  xlab("Habitat") + ylab("FEve")  + theme_bw()  + facet_wrap(~River, ncol=5)+
  scale_colour_manual(values=Plot_colours) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, size=20), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=20),
        strip.text = element_text(size=20), 
        axis.title.x =element_text(size=25),
        axis.title.y =element_text(size=25),
        plot.tag=element_text(size=30),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
        legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.position = c("none"), 
        legend.text=element_text(size=20), 
        legend.title=element_text(size=25)) + labs(tag = "e)")
```

Data structure as follows from dput() function:

```
structure(list(Habitat = c("Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", 
"Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", 
"Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", 
"Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", 
"Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", 
"Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", 
"Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", 
"Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", 
"Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", 
"Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", 
"Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", 
"Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", 
"Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", 
"Gravel", "Gravel", "Gravel", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", 
"Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", 
"Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", 
"Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", 
"Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", 
"Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", 
"Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", 
"Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", 
"Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", 
"Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", 
"Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Sand", "Silt", "Silt", 
"Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", 
"Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", 
"Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", 
"Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", 
"Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", 
"Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", 
"Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", 
"Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", 
"Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", 
"Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", 
"Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt", "Silt"), River = c("Mill", 
"Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", 
"Mill", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", 
"Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", 
"Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", 
"Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", 
"Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", 
"Mill", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Frome", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", 
"Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", 
"Wool", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", 
"Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", 
"Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", 
"Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", 
"Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", 
"Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", 
"Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", 
"Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", 
"Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", 
"Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Gadder", 
"Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", 
"Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Gadder", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", 
"Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", 
"Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Little Stour", 
"Little Stour", "Little Stour", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", 
"Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Mill", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Frome", 
"Frome", "Frome", "Frome", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", 
"Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool", "Wool"), Feve = c(0.506977035, 
0.658168517, 0.5552127, 0.674176982, 0.568126029, 0.470484617, 
0.546243187, 0.557337037, 0.549162764, 0.51482439, 0.296783107, 
0.540411614, 0.441655613, 0.748657363, 0.586072179, 0.562687945, 
0.679463256, 0.640924761, 0.76043005, 0.570535503, 0.345381789, 
0.7466591, 0.697030182, 0.397968864, 0.370615261, 0.512819438, 
0.251546229, 0.570256251, 0.346010274, 0.243989438, 0.879881015, 
0.578277252, 0.586240417, 0.653396257, 0.641415819, 0.524595729, 
0.536800538, 0.519825276, 0.521801451, 0.465289634, 0.838068847, 
0.487272624, 0.665124783, 0.629608162, 0.400335866, 0.538598014, 
0.614481336, 0.50953854, 0.564571301, 0.434708346, 0.603286877, 
0.389340894, 0.451569201, 0.664220591, 0.625448998, 0.47830779, 
0.610677015, 0.592997649, 0.389771325, 0.345401462, 0.368971704, 
0.515001741, 0.49651484, 0.49955372, 0.538803174, 0.430966396, 
0.601647539, 0.450264668, 0.510230055, 0.455519866, 0.382308378, 
0.541156034, 0.48855963, 0.454064886, 0.628266636, 0.588126731, 
0.694832118, 0.721497295, 0.652815016, 0.614719973, 0.629744193, 
0.556498854, 0.599436173, 0.537701923, 0.634997581, 0.422792666, 
0.54448257, 0.61526252, 0.644073418, 0.463178528, 0.53049777, 
0.73680085, 0.654108793, 0.508193606, 0.784465676, 0.625011416, 
0.370492072, 0.615810028, 0.758132891, 0.733838212, 0.699321368, 
0.680547958, 0.631187485, 0.580031627, 0.669025786, 0.578582091, 
0.720102863, 0.610043844, 0.705463595, 0.736388029, 0.626156558, 
0.665129554, 0.736158535, 0.635527589, 0.667806898, 0.719755199, 
0.516756193, 0.743297471, 0.385352895, 0.032755073, 0.370695443, 
0.411080389, 0.610129264, 0.44115061, 0.436587861, 0.646474891, 
0.4632019, 0.544676459, 0.70722696, 0.775250617, 0.386924944, 
0.681213071, 0.785576735, 0.653825379, 0.765341039, 0.531730415, 
0.496468683, 0.568045574, 0.559047785, 0.618799013, 0.595831336, 
0.62825441, 0.566092305, 0.424579031, 0.475876404, 0.456873779, 
0.547629079, 0.650585859, 0.573124305, 0.723337968, 0.5208022, 
0.682698101, 0.639284704, 0.633086197, 0.561406514, 0.680181535, 
0.459038805, 0.471462813, 0.731018956, 0.634841981, 0.721187209, 
0.702791349, 0.744408386, 0.595889197, 0.48472181, 0.560199898, 
0.608437475, 0.707858755, 0.675909255, 0.735408435, 0.435542404, 
0.6053562, 0.595449887, 0.520702662, 0.645871555, 0.557698442, 
0.771899899, 0.508251962, 0.694331707, 0.549159191, 0.53994213, 
0.547164043, 0.644919934, 0.699196417, 0.735875306, 0.667984496, 
0.630353871, 0.718764016, 0.398504512, 0.668611595, 0.436300968, 
0.562561037, 0.656273832, 0.71630428, 0.626932262, 0.733307825, 
0.669013893, 0.837176403, 0.298035491, 0.810612337, 0.777539406, 
0.790902907, 0.713633147, 0.626837346, 0.571953853, 0.745992741, 
0.533352203, 0.755656202, 0.548742714, 0.327365258, 0.72424353, 
0.528402042, 0.540123857, 0.688264186, 0.541088378, 0.675038588, 
0.71309915, 0.651328765, 0.56050516, 0.632870384, 0.480536671, 
0.549664771, 0.58966238, 0.648690841, 0.543502869, 0.583063433, 
0.522673603, 0.656145405, 0.389555701, 0.52203683, 0.560684461, 
0.469447718, 0.639486253, 0.594082402, 0.57815447, 0.633922141, 
0.480927001, 0.605528679, 0.665749149, 0.401690615, 0.344411136, 
0.382189728, 0.681118444, 0.519816427, 0.47681727, 0.470170962, 
0.478776858, 0.694232011, 0.696928503, 0.705804165, 0.691504978, 
0.771564279, 0.634355679, 0.540054854, 0.580389632, 0.648298349, 
0.599541806, 0.375901167, 0.471454503, 0.361917446, 0.487022267, 
0.597901339)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -262L))
```

Answer (score 2):

If we want to add an extra facet that contains *all* the data, we can achieve this by row-binding a second copy of the data frame onto the original, where the faceting variable is replaced with the single string `"all"`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Summer %>%
  bind_rows(Summer %>% mutate(River = 'ALL')) %>%
  mutate(River = factor(River, c(levels(factor(Summer$River)), 'ALL'))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Habitat, Feve, colour = Habitat)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1), size = 2, alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_errorbar(stat = 'summary', fun.data = 'mean_se', color = 'black',
                width = 0.2, linewidth = 0.7) +
  geom_point(stat = 'summary', fun = 'mean', color = 'black',
             aes(group = interaction(River, Habitat))) +
  facet_wrap(~ River, ncol = 3) +
  labs(x = "Habitat", y = "FEve", tag = "e") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)  + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        legend.position = c("none"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Allan. I have added my data to the original question. Is there a way to include the all function within the code formatting I am using (pasted in the question) as otherwise I will need to edit all my other figures to match the above style. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @KateMathers it's just exactly the same as I showed except with the variable names changed to those in your own data frame. See my update. Note that you don't need to precalculate `SummarySE`, since this can be done automatically inside `geom_errorbar`. You may need to tweak the code, since I have had to change some of your theme elements to fit the plot on my screen, and I didn't have your plot colours. Also, it is very difficult to see the errorbars, so I have made these black and made the points jitter a little. Again this is a matter of taste that you can tweak yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I really really appreciate this. Such a help. I was wondering is there a way of getting the Centre point back into the SE plots. I've played around with the formatting but I think the way of including all means the geom_point adds all data to the plot.  Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: @KateMathers sure - see my update

Comment: perfect! This is great. Sorry final question is it possible for All to be at the end of the graph order. I can reorder the factors but as all is not in my original data I am not quite sure how to deal with this. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @KateMathers see my update

Comment: Absolutely amazing. Thanks so much for all your help. This has worked perfectly and produced a stunning graph! Thanks again.